# How to catch stdout stream in ffmpeg then pipe it to v4l2loopback

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to pipe my h264 stream to ffmpeg and then to my v4l2loopback device. Problem is that I'm fairly new to linux, so just can't get it working. 
The stream can be outputted to stdout, but I do not know how to catch it again with ffmpeg and then again pipe it to my v4l2loopback device.

Does anybody know how this could be done or maybe a pointer on how to solve it?

This is the capture program:

PS! You can find the options for the capture program almost in the bottom of the code.

```c
/*
 *  V4L2 video capture example, modified by Derek Molloy for the Logitech C920 camera
 *  Modifications, added the -F mode for H264 capture and associated help detail
 *  www.derekmolloy.ie
 *
 *  V4L2 video capture example
 *
 *  This program can be used and distributed without restrictions.
 *
 *      This program is provided with the V4L2 API
 * see http://linuxtv.org/docs.php for more information
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <getopt.h>             /* getopt_long() */

#include <fcntl.h>              /* low-level i/o */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/videodev2.h>

#define CLEAR(x) memset(&(x), 0, sizeof(x))

enum io_method {
        IO_METHOD_READ,
        IO_METHOD_MMAP,
        IO_METHOD_USERPTR,
};

struct buffer {
        void   *start;
        size_t  length;
};

static char            *dev_name;
static enum io_method   io = IO_METHOD_MMAP;
static int              fd = -1;
struct buffer          *buffers;
static unsigned int     n_buffers;
static int              out_buf;
static int              force_format = 0;
static int              frame_count = 100;

static void errno_exit(const char *s)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "%s error %d, %s\n", s, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static int xioctl(int fh, int request, void *arg)
{
        int r;

        do {
                r = ioctl(fh, request, arg);
        } while (-1 == r && EINTR == errno);

        return r;
}

static void process_image(const void *p, int size)
{
        if (out_buf)
                fwrite(p, size, 1, stdout);

        fflush(stderr);
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
        fflush(stdout);
}

static int read_frame(void)
{
        struct v4l2_buffer buf;
        unsigned int i;

        switch (io) {
        case IO_METHOD_READ:
                if (-1 == read(fd, buffers[0].start, buffers[0].length)) {
                        switch (errno) {
                        case EAGAIN:
                                return 0;

                        case EIO:
                                /* Could ignore EIO, see spec. */

                                /* fall through */

                        default:
                                errno_exit("read");
                        }
                }

                process_image(buffers[0].start, buffers[0].length);
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_MMAP:
                CLEAR(buf);

                buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf)) {
                        switch (errno) {
                        case EAGAIN:
                                return 0;

                        case EIO:
                                /* Could ignore EIO, see spec. */

                                /* fall through */

                        default:
                                errno_exit("VIDIOC_DQBUF");
                        }
                }

                assert(buf.index < n_buffers);

                process_image(buffers[buf.index].start, buf.bytesused);

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_QBUF");
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_USERPTR:
                CLEAR(buf);

                buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR;

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf)) {
                        switch (errno) {
                        case EAGAIN:
                                return 0;

                        case EIO:
                                /* Could ignore EIO, see spec. */

                                /* fall through */

                        default:
                                errno_exit("VIDIOC_DQBUF");
                        }
                }

                for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
                        if (buf.m.userptr == (unsigned long)buffers[i].start
                            && buf.length == buffers[i].length)
                                break;

                assert(i < n_buffers);

                process_image((void *)buf.m.userptr, buf.bytesused);

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_QBUF");
                break;
        }

        return 1;
}

static void mainloop(void)
{
        unsigned int count;
    unsigned int loopIsInfinite = 0;

        if (frame_count == 0) loopIsInfinite = 1; //infinite loop
    count = frame_count;

        while ((count-- > 0) || loopIsInfinite) {
                for (;;) {
                        fd_set fds;
                        struct timeval tv;
                        int r;

                        FD_ZERO(&fds);
                        FD_SET(fd, &fds);

                        /* Timeout. */
                        tv.tv_sec = 2;
                        tv.tv_usec = 0;

                        r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

                        if (-1 == r) {
                                if (EINTR == errno)
                                        continue;
                                errno_exit("select");
                        }

                        if (0 == r) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "select timeout\n");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }

                        if (read_frame())
                                break;
                        /* EAGAIN - continue select loop. */
                }
        }
}

static void stop_capturing(void)
{
        enum v4l2_buf_type type;

        switch (io) {
        case IO_METHOD_READ:
                /* Nothing to do. */
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_MMAP:
        case IO_METHOD_USERPTR:
                type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_STREAMOFF");
                break;
        }
}

static void start_capturing(void)
{
        unsigned int i;
        enum v4l2_buf_type type;

        switch (io) {
        case IO_METHOD_READ:
                /* Nothing to do. */
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_MMAP:
                for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i) {
                        struct v4l2_buffer buf;

                        CLEAR(buf);
                        buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                        buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                        buf.index = i;

                        if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf))
                                errno_exit("VIDIOC_QBUF");
                }
                type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_STREAMON");
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_USERPTR:
                for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i) {
                        struct v4l2_buffer buf;

                        CLEAR(buf);
                        buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                        buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR;
                        buf.index = i;
                        buf.m.userptr = (unsigned long)buffers[i].start;
                        buf.length = buffers[i].length;

                        if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf))
                                errno_exit("VIDIOC_QBUF");
                }
                type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_STREAMON");
                break;
        }
}

static void uninit_device(void)
{
        unsigned int i;

        switch (io) {
        case IO_METHOD_READ:
                free(buffers[0].start);
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_MMAP:
                for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
                        if (-1 == munmap(buffers[i].start, buffers[i].length))
                                errno_exit("munmap");
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_USERPTR:
                for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
                        free(buffers[i].start);
                break;
        }

        free(buffers);
}

static void init_read(unsigned int buffer_size)
{
        buffers = calloc(1, sizeof(*buffers));

        if (!buffers) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        buffers[0].length = buffer_size;
        buffers[0].start = malloc(buffer_size);

        if (!buffers[0].start) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

static void init_mmap(void)
{
        struct v4l2_requestbuffers req;

        CLEAR(req);

        req.count = 4;
        req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

        if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req)) {
                if (EINVAL == errno) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s does not support "
                                 "memory mapping\n", dev_name);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } else {
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_REQBUFS");
                }
        }

        if (req.count < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient buffer memory on %s\n",
                         dev_name);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));

        if (!buffers) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (n_buffers = 0; n_buffers < req.count; ++n_buffers) {
                struct v4l2_buffer buf;

                CLEAR(buf);

                buf.type        = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory      = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buf.index       = n_buffers;

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_QUERYBUF");

                buffers[n_buffers].length = buf.length;
                buffers[n_buffers].start =
                        mmap(NULL /* start anywhere */,
                              buf.length,
                              PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE /* required */,
                              MAP_SHARED /* recommended */,
                              fd, buf.m.offset);

                if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[n_buffers].start)
                        errno_exit("mmap");
        }
}

static void init_userp(unsigned int buffer_size)
{
        struct v4l2_requestbuffers req;

        CLEAR(req);

        req.count  = 4;
        req.type   = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR;

        if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req)) {
                if (EINVAL == errno) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s does not support "
                                 "user pointer i/o\n", dev_name);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } else {
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_REQBUFS");
                }
        }

        buffers = calloc(4, sizeof(*buffers));

        if (!buffers) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (n_buffers = 0; n_buffers < 4; ++n_buffers) {
                buffers[n_buffers].length = buffer_size;
                buffers[n_buffers].start = malloc(buffer_size);

                if (!buffers[n_buffers].start) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
}

static void init_device(void)
{
        struct v4l2_capability cap;
        struct v4l2_cropcap cropcap;
        struct v4l2_crop crop;
        struct v4l2_format fmt;
        unsigned int min;

        if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap)) {
                if (EINVAL == errno) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s is no V4L2 device\n",
                                 dev_name);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } else {
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_QUERYCAP");
                }
        }

        if (!(cap.capabilities & V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s is no video capture device\n",
                         dev_name);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        switch (io) {
        case IO_METHOD_READ:
                if (!(cap.capabilities & V4L2_CAP_READWRITE)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s does not support read i/o\n",
                                 dev_name);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_MMAP:
        case IO_METHOD_USERPTR:
                if (!(cap.capabilities & V4L2_CAP_STREAMING)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s does not support streaming i/o\n",
                                 dev_name);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
        }


        /* Select video input, video standard and tune here. */


        CLEAR(cropcap);

        cropcap.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;

        if (0 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_CROPCAP, &cropcap)) {
                crop.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                crop.c = cropcap.defrect; /* reset to default */

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_CROP, &crop)) {
                        switch (errno) {
                        case EINVAL:
                                /* Cropping not supported. */
                                break;
                        default:
                                /* Errors ignored. */
                                break;
                        }
                }
        } else {
                /* Errors ignored. */
        }


        CLEAR(fmt);

        fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    fprintf(stderr, "Force Format %d\n", force_format);
        if (force_format) {
        if (force_format==2){
                    fmt.fmt.pix.width       = 1920;     
                fmt.fmt.pix.height      = 1080;  
            fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_H264;
                    fmt.fmt.pix.field       = V4L2_FIELD_INTERLACED;
        }
        else if(force_format==1){
            fmt.fmt.pix.width   = 640;
            fmt.fmt.pix.height  = 480;
            fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV;
            fmt.fmt.pix.field   = V4L2_FIELD_INTERLACED;
        }

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_S_FMT");

                /* Note VIDIOC_S_FMT may change width and height. */
        } else {
                /* Preserve original settings as set by v4l2-ctl for example */
                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_G_FMT, &fmt))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_G_FMT");
        }

        /* Buggy driver paranoia. */
        min = fmt.fmt.pix.width * 2;
        if (fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline < min)
                fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline = min;
        min = fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline * fmt.fmt.pix.height;
        if (fmt.fmt.pix.sizeimage < min)
                fmt.fmt.pix.sizeimage = min;

        switch (io) {
        case IO_METHOD_READ:
                init_read(fmt.fmt.pix.sizeimage);
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_MMAP:
                init_mmap();
                break;

        case IO_METHOD_USERPTR:
                init_userp(fmt.fmt.pix.sizeimage);
                break;
        }
}

static void close_device(void)
{
        if (-1 == close(fd))
                errno_exit("close");

        fd = -1;
}

static void open_device(void)
{
        struct stat st;

        if (-1 == stat(dev_name, &st)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot identify '%s': %d, %s\n",
                         dev_name, errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (!S_ISCHR(st.st_mode)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s is no device\n", dev_name);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fd = open(dev_name, O_RDWR /* required */ | O_NONBLOCK, 0);

        if (-1 == fd) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open '%s': %d, %s\n",
                         dev_name, errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

static void usage(FILE *fp, int argc, char **argv)
{
        fprintf(fp,
                 "Usage: %s [options]\n\n"
                 "Version 1.3\n"
                 "Options:\n"
                 "-d | --device name   Video device name [%s]\n"
                 "-h | --help          Print this message\n"
                 "-m | --mmap          Use memory mapped buffers [default]\n"
                 "-r | --read          Use read() calls\n"
                 "-u | --userp         Use application allocated buffers\n"
                 "-o | --output        Outputs stream to stdout\n"
                 "-f | --format        Force format to 640x480 YUYV\n"
         "-F | --formatH264    Force format to 1920x1080 H264\n"
                 "-c | --count         Number of frames to grab [%i] - use 0 for infinite\n"
                 "\n"
         "Example usage: capture -F -o -c 300 > output.raw\n"
         "Captures 300 frames of H264 at 1920x1080 - use raw2mpg4 script to convert to mpg4\n",
                 argv[0], dev_name, frame_count);
}

static const char short_options[] = "d:hmruofFc:";

static const struct option
long_options[] = {
        { "device", required_argument, NULL, 'd' },
        { "help",   no_argument,       NULL, 'h' },
        { "mmap",   no_argument,       NULL, 'm' },
        { "read",   no_argument,       NULL, 'r' },
        { "userp",  no_argument,       NULL, 'u' },
        { "output", no_argument,       NULL, 'o' },
        { "format", no_argument,       NULL, 'f' },
    { "formatH264", no_argument,   NULL, 'F' },
        { "count",  required_argument, NULL, 'c' },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        dev_name = "/dev/video0";

        for (;;) {
                int idx;
                int c;

                c = getopt_long(argc, argv,
                                short_options, long_options, &idx);

                if (-1 == c)
                        break;

                switch (c) {
                case 0: /* getopt_long() flag */
                        break;

                case 'd':
                        dev_name = optarg;
                        break;

                case 'h':
                        usage(stdout, argc, argv);
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

                case 'm':
                        io = IO_METHOD_MMAP;
                        break;

                case 'r':
                        io = IO_METHOD_READ;
                        break;

                case 'u':
                        io = IO_METHOD_USERPTR;
                        break;

                case 'o':
                        out_buf++;
                        break;

                case 'f':
                        force_format=1;
                        break;

        case 'F':
            force_format=2;
            break;

                case 'c':
                        errno = 0;
                        frame_count = strtol(optarg, NULL, 0);
                        if (errno)
                                errno_exit(optarg);
                        break;

                default:
                        usage(stderr, argc, argv);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        open_device();
        init_device();
        start_capturing();
        mainloop();
        stop_capturing();
        uninit_device();
        close_device();
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 0;
}
```

It's a modified version of a V4L2 video capture example. 
Then I know that if I have outputed the streame to a file I would have to run this command to convert the raw format to mp4 format:

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i output.raw -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

And the v4l2loopback program I'm using is foud here:
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

------------------Update------------------

Okay. So I got the pipe from the capture program to ffmpeg working. It captures, decodes the h264 and I can write it to a mp4 file with this command:

`./capture -F -d /dev/video0 -o | ffmpeg -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy out.mp4`

Now I am trying to get the last pipe working with this command:

```
./capture -F -d /dev/video0 -o | ffmpeg -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -f mp4 - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3
```

I get these errors:

- muxer does not support non seekable output
- Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last command you are piping an `MP4` to GStreamer. See the `-f mp4 -` part:

`./capture -F -d /dev/video0 -o | ffmpeg -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -f mp4 - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3`

What you want to do is pipe the `H.264` stream inside the MP4 instead.

Try replacing `-f mp4 -` with `-f h264 -`.

In fact you could probably skip entirely the creation of an MP4 and just do:

`./capture -F -d /dev/video0 -o | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3`

since the `-F` option forces H.264.

Comment: So I checked the supported formats of the loopback device and got a list with nothing on it. But I don't think I is supossed to either before a stream is connected to it. At v4l2loopbacks github site a list of supported formats is listed and H264 is among the supported formats. It can be found here
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/v4l2loopback_formats.h
Any ideas where it goes wrong?

Comment: You are right about the accepted formats, I had your other question in mind. See if the updated answer helps.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions, with no luck. I susspect maybe it is because of the driver that I use for the v4l2loopback. I had to use an older version to get it working, so maybe thats the reason. Thank you for your effort aergistal! I'll poste my solution here as soon as I get somthing working:)

Comment: I tested the GStreamer command with an FFmpeg raw H.264 input and it works. So it could be something in `capture` too. Watch the log for errors.

Comment: I'll test it today. And btw I had the newest loopback drivers installed

Comment: Okay so I start the script I get to "Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock"
Then I get this error:
(gst-launch-0.10:2701): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(gst-launch-0.10:2701): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: "gst_structure_get_name: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
Caught SIGSEGV accessing address (nil)
..Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch 2701' to continue debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.
"
If I add "! Decodebin !" in between fdsrc and v4l2sink I actually get a YU12 image, but now it is way to slow